# Pandas & Matplotlib: personalize the date format in a line chart

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, predictive

I want to make the dates on the x- axis look more prettier, currently the dates cannot be even read. what is the best way to do it.
Below is the code and also the actual graph picture

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd

df = dataset
# gca stands for 'get current axis'
ax = plt.gca()
y1 = df['Predicted_Lower']
y2 = df['Predicted_Upper']
x = df['Date']
ax.fill_between(x,y1, y2, facecolor="#CC6666", alpha=0.7)
df.plot(kind='line',x='Date',y='Predicted_Lower',color='white',ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='line',x='Date',y='Predicted_Upper',color='white', ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='line',x='Date',y='Predicted', color='yellow', ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='line',x='Date',y='Actuals', color='green', ax=ax)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I believe you're looking for a combination of https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/major_minor_demo.html and https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html. If you post some sample data that we can copy, it will be easier to provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: @MatthewBorish it is connected to mysqlserver

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the number of labels, by settings `locs` and `labels` parameters using [`matplotlib.pyplot.xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html), for example get the current `locs` and `labels` and only plot one-third of them:

```
# ...
df.plot(kind='line',x='Date',y='Actuals', color='green', ax=ax)
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.xticks(locs[::3], labels[::3], rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Try using fewer items like `plt.xticks(locs[::5], labels[::5], rotation=45)`, is hard to tell without the data.

Comment: it is displaying all dates as 00-00-00

Comment: Well based on your picture, all dates are `00-00-00`, can you post maybe the first 30 lines of the data frame: `df.head(30).to_json()`